# Is Starvation possible in First Come first serve CPU scheduling algorithm

Tags: operating-systems, process-scheduling

Let's say  if we have an infinite process that never yields such that other process dosent get to run. Since FCFS is a non preemptive scheduler does it leads to starvation

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What research have you done?  Why do you think FCFS implies a non-emptive scheduler?

Answer (score -1):

OS would generally trap these type of process and core would be dumped.